# Create/trigger Pod when new file is uploaded to PVC kubernetes

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes.
I have Rest Api running in a pod through which we are uploading a file and storing that on pod's local pvc.
I want to create a new pod in my kubernetes cluster whenever new file is uploaded in persistence storage PVC.
Any guidance how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you add some more context to this question. If you have a PVC already then it is attached to some k8s object , the application running in the pod of that object must trigger a new pod on addition of new file , is that what you are expecting.
Also how are files being uploaded to PVC. Are you on any cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you can monitor files created on the host where they are stored and then invoke the kubernetes API to create the pod. See the links below for pod creation.

- [How to create Pod from REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176283/how-to-create-pod-from-rest-api)
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#create-create-a-pod

Comment: creating pod through rest api that can be done with this. how to monitor the files?

Comment: you can use inotify to watch files from filesystem. https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/utils/inotify. for the python version see also https://pypi.org/project/inotify/