# Is possible to wake containers on RabbitMQ message?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I’m trying to use RabbitMQ in a containerized microservices infrastructure and, by default, containers are shut down when in idle
I wanted to keep this kind of handling of idling but, afaik, the container must be awake in order to listen to messages
Is there a way to make RabbitMQ wake up the consumer containers subbed to the interested queue?

I've tried to search online but no one is making any reference to what I needed

What I imagined is something that works like this:

```js
                                               ┌────────────► Consumer
                                               │
Producer ─── message ────► RabbitMQ ── wakes ──┼────────────► Consumer
                                               │
                                               └────────────► Consumer
```

Then, RabbitMQ after triggered the containers should deliver the messages

```js
                           ┌────────────► Consumer
                           │
      RabbitMQ ── message -┼────────────► Consumer
                           │
                           └────────────► Consumer
```

When a container wakes creates a channel so what I really need is just the "wake" command on message that should be sent, as told before only to interested containers/microservices

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "management" pod that is always up & running and consumes messages from the queue, and decides when to create the consumer pods. You can create the pods via API as you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176283/how-to-create-pod-from-rest-api).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I can understand (correct me if I'm wrong) there is a way to declare to RabbitMQ the address of every microservice to interact with. My question now is, how can RabbitMQ keep trace of what microservice is subscribed to a queue?